# Create product attribute type is file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, file-upload

How to create a product attribute in file type in Magento 2
our requirement is a particular product-wise Pdf upload in Magento
2 and shows a product view page in Magento 2. So How can I sort it?
please give me suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [these steps](https://webkul.com/blog/create-and-manage-product-file-type-attribute-in-magento-2/) to create Product File Type Attribute in Magento 2

https://webkul.com/blog/create-and-manage-product-file-type-attribute-in-magento-2/

Comment: Hi @DJ Dev
Thank you for Info.
I have already try to this Extention but can't be working in magneto 2
Because I face some issue like when I upload a file like PDF so can't be save the data and can't show delete option in this Agreement file attribute.

Comment: @MOHIT Are you getting any error after applied these steps? Please share if you are getting any error.

Comment: I have faced some error related module like the module is working perfect
for me but can't showing delete option and checkbox in admin side.
Thank you.